# How to read XML file contents as a string from a CSV feeder variable?

Tags: karate

The value of order_contents is passed from a CSV file defined in scala file.
order_contents in the CSV file is defined as "read('classpath:data/XML-Order.txt')"
XML-Order.txt contains a string that is in XML format. Due to some limitations, I want to read it as string. :)

```
Feature: checkOrder

 Background:
 Given url getOrder.URL
 * def contents = __gatling.order_contents

@checkOrder
 Scenario: checkOrder
* string orderContents = contents
* print orderContents
```

When running, the print statement shows only read('classpath:data/XML-Order.txt') as a string but not the contents of the string

BUT By hardcoding the path, it will achieve the result as what I have expected.

```
Feature: checkOrder

 Background:
 Given url getOrder.URL
 * def contents = __gatling.order_contents

@checkOrder
 Scenario: checkOrder
* string orderContents = read('classpath:data/XML-Order.txt')
* print orderContents
```

When running, the print statement will shows the XML string that is in XML-Order.txt file.

Also tried to do this

```
 * def test = <contents>
 * string value = test
```

But I am getting the below error when printing org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 24; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

But I want to implement a more dynamic way of defining the data via CSV file. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 suggestions.

Just have the path of the file held in `__gatling.order_contents` - e.g: `classpath:data/XML-Order.txt`

Then this will work, and note that there is a [`karate.readAsString()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#read-file-as-string) option:

```
* def orderContents = karate.readAsString(__gatling.order_contents)
```

Else, write a Java utility to do exactly what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475

Comment: Great! This solution worked. Why din i think of this.

* string orderContents = karate.readAsString(__gatling.order_contents)
* print orderContents