is there a way to download response files from karate?
I have a response from karate api testing as encrypted values, like so: ��@��   �۷ڔ~d�
It is actually 3 files abc.json, abc.xml and abc.xlsx. In postman I can save the response and a zip file get download with all the 3 files. Is there a way to replicate this postman functionality in Karate. I need the files for log keeping.
I tried
* karate.write(response,'abc.zip')

and if I save it as txt file then only the encrypted data gets saved.
* karate.write(response , 'abc.txt')

I get the error that it is corrupted.
I tried the write method but it did not work.

You can try with using responseBytes instead which is guaranteed to be the exact binary data that may have come as the response. I just tried it with image data and it works fine:
* url 'https://httpbin.org/image/png'
* method get
* karate.write(responseBytes, 'test.png')

If that doesn't work, then I suggest you write custom code to handle it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593057/143475
