# Is there a way we can chain the scenarios in karate like java method chaining

Tags: karate

I have been using Karate for the past 6 months, I am really impressed with the features it offers.
I know karate is meant to test API(s) individually but we are also trying to use it for E2E tests that involves calling multiple scenarios step by step. 
Our feature file looks like below
1.Call Feature1:Scenario1
2.Call Feature2:Scenario2
.....
Note: We are re-using a scenarios for both API Testing and E2E testing.Sometimes I find it difficult to remember all feature files.
Can we chain the scenario call like java, I doubt feature file will let us to do that. We need your valuable suggestion. pls let us know if you feel our approach is not correct

[image]

Comment: I need more Information. What do you mean by API and E2E testing? Both could be done by a CI Job or could be put into a separate E2E testing application that runs like any other normal application in the cloud. 

What do you mean by "Cannot remember all feature files"? Are you using karate in manual test cases and you have to call all scenarios manually? 

Would be great If you could describe a classical API Test (what you do aso.) and how this is different from an E2E test.

Comment: I have attached the picture that differentiates 2.

Comment: Ok, understood the way you create feature files that serve as a composition of other reusable scenarios.
And I guess your are calling E2E feature files selectively in your test automation?

And,.. the screenshot shows a cheat sheet? This isn't a screenshot from karate code, is it?

Comment: yes that is correct, I am sorry pls consider the image that explains the intent. I am planning to use karate for Integration/load/component and E2E. If I could chain the call (with intellij suggestion) I can achieve all these things.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd like to quote the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure

> Variables set using def in the Background will be re-set before every `Scenario`. If you are looking for a way to do something only once per `Feature`, take a look at `callonce`. On the other hand, if you are expecting a variable in the `Background` to be modified by one `Scenario` so that later ones can see the updated value - that is not how you should think of them, and you should combine your 'flow' into one `Scenario`. Keep in mind that you should be able to comment-out a `Scenario` or skip some via tags without impacting any others. Note that the parallel runner will run `Scenario`-s in parallel, which means they can run in any order.

So by default, I actually recommend teams to have `Scenario`-s with multiple API calls within them. There is nothing wrong with that, and I really don't understand why some folks assume that you should have a `Scenario` for every `GET` or `POST` etc. I thought the ["hello world" example](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hello-world) would have made that clear, but evidently not.

If you have multiple `Scenario-s` in a `Feature` just run the feature, and all `Scenario-s` will be executed or "chained". So what's the problem ?

I think you need to change some of your assumptions. Karate is designed for integration testing. If you really need to have a separate set of tests that test one API at a time, please create separate feature files. The whole point of Karate is that there is so little code needed - that code-duplication is perfectly ok.

Let me point you to [this article by Google](https://testing.googleblog.com/2019/12/testing-on-toilet-tests-too-dry-make.html). For test-automation, you should NOT be trying to re-use things all over the place. It does more harm than good.

For a great example of what happens when you try to apply "too much re-use" in Karate, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

Comment: Thank you peter I understand the objective better now.