# how to define order for execution of feature files in karate framework

Tags: karate, junit5

I have few feature files in specific subfolders, And I want to execute those feature files according to my defined order.

So how can we run the feature files in a specific order?

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create one feature and then make calls to the other features. But this means you will lose the biggest benefit of Karate which is that you can run tests in parallel.

Any needs beyond this, please assume are not supported (or will never be supported) by Karate. Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080568/143475