# How to run karate tags in sequence

Tags: automation, karate, cucumber-junit, karate-call-single

I have multiple feature file with the tags @run_first @run_second @run_third

file m.feature
Feature:  test feature1
Background:
* print " test feature1"
@run_first
Scenario:  run first feature test

file a.feature
Feature:  test feature1
Background:
* print " test feature2"
@run_second
Scenario:  run second feature test

feature file is running on alphabetical order but requirement is run the feature file  in sequence defined in tags @run_first @run_second @run_third
first it run all the feature file with tags @run_first after @run_second then @run_third so on.

com.intuit.karate version 1.4.1

my case all the feature file is running alphabetical sequence. Want to run feature file in tags wise sequence.

Answer (score 0):

No this is currently not possible. See this answer for related information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75132679/143475

There is an open feature request for perhaps what you are looking for, you can consider contributing code to make this happen: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2235