# karate how to change config value thru scenario

Tags: karate

How to overwrite a karate-config.js variable thru a Scenario.
I tried using Set, but did not work.
My karate-config.js and feature files are as below:
Though not getting any error but *cpNumber*  value did not change, printing *234455* not 123.
Can some-one pls help me over-writing a karate-config.js variable.

```
function fn(){
     var config = {
        cpNumber : "234455"
        }
        return config
    }

    Scenario: Update  scenario
        * karate.set(cpNumber, "123")
        * print cpNumber
```

Comment: as far as I know this should work. you never know, maybe karate has a bug. please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and note that a simple `* def cpNumber = '100'` should work

Comment: * def cpNumber = '100', creating local variable and assigning value to it. But what i'm trying to achieve is to overwrite a config variable that is written in karate-config.js file.

Comment: I still don't understand your question - but let me just say that once `karate-config.js` runs you cannot over-write variables for *other* scenarios. please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080568/143475 - and if you still have a question, follow the process I linked above please

Comment: Thanks for quick response on this question. I have gone thru above post and agree. But instead restricting to over-write config variables, if we allow user to update, he may use these updated variables in other scenarios. It could be feature at the same time.

Comment: I have nothing more to add about the design of karate and why every `Scenario` **has** to start from a "clean slate". you are welcome to contribute code via a PR so that others understand what you want. once reviewed, if everyone agrees we can certainly add that code to karate

Comment: Thanks for invitation to contribute code, but I'm not that much expert. I'm a normal qa automation lead and thought to share my views. Any ways its very useful and saving lot of our time in testing api, you really awesome, seeing you/your team developing such a marvel, kudos, keep up good work, thanks a lot again for great support.