# match each response contains a property that can be value1 or value2 in karate

Tags: karate

i get this as response:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "The Russian",
    "type": "fiction",
    "available": true
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Just as I Am",
    "type": "non-fiction",
    "available": false
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "The Vanishing Half",
    "type": "fiction",
    "available": true
}
]
```

how can i match that all responses have type with either 'fiction' or 'non-fiction'

i tried this :

```
  * def booktypes = ['fiction','non-fiction']
  * def schema = { type: '#? booktypes.contains(_)' }
  * match response contains schema
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
* def types = ['fiction', 'non-fiction']
* match each response contains { type: '#? types.includes(_)' }
```

The JS equivalent for the Java `contains()` is unfortunately named `includes()`.

Comment: that correct sir, thank you, i would never know this if you didn't tell me, Documentation should be updated !

Comment: sir i would like to ask here cause they stopped me from asking :
how can i reuse a variable in a scenario in another scenario, i got the generated access token but i cannot use it in the next scenario

Comment: @roudlek read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080568/143475