# How different values can be passed to different feature file refering the same variable

Tags: variables, karate

Using karate framework

For Example:

A.feature file

Scenario: Test
Given url 'abc'

- def number = 12345
  And request {tyu:'#(number)',dhd:'lkj'}
  When method put
  Then status 200

B.feature file

Scenario: Test2
Given url 'pqr'
And request {tyu:'#(number)'}
When method put
Then status 200

Actually what is happening is
tyu variable is storing the value it generates for the first time , the first feature file returns successful response
and other feature file fails with duplicate reference value for the tyu variable

Expected
Everytime the variable tyu should be able to get different value in the request body
tyu is acting as the reference variable (expected it should be different)
tyu is refering a method from a java class

Comment: besides the linked question, read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080568/143475