# Pass a variable to another API scenario feature with Karate

Tags: testing, karate

In a scenario that returns a token to me when my app connects, I want to pass this token on when I call another scenario like this:

```
* def connection = call read('classpath:api/commons/connection.feature')
    * def accessToken = connection.accessToken

    * def createClient = call read('classpath:api/commons/create-client.feature') {accessToken: accessToken}
```

First point: by doing this, I don't get the token back in the other scenario.

```
* def path = read('classpath:api/paths.json')
* url apiUrl
* print accessToken
```

returns nothing at all

I was wondering whether it was good practice to split API tests along these lines. In my UI tests, I split my tests as much as possible to obtain reusable bricks.

Thanks

Comment: I think this should answer all your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080568/143475

Answer (score 1):

```
Feature: Calling Feature

  Background: 
    * def result = callonce read('CalledFile.feature') {username: 'admin',password: 'password123'}
    * def tokenValue = result.response.token

Scenario: print background token value
    * print 'token value is:',tokenValue
```

token value can be shared across scenarios by using Background section. In my answer I have used Background section and used callonce keyword, so the call to api will be made only once and token value will be cached.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35696663)

Comment: The author was finding it difficult to share the token value across scenarios because of not using background section. In my answer i have used background section and used callonce keyword to call the token generation api once so the call to api will be made only once and token value will be cached.

Comment: Mind adding that to the answer? I came from reviews, your answer was flagged for length,  and couldn’t make a better judgement call

Comment: Added the comment under my answer.