In the Karate UI, I can transfer the value of a variable between scenarios
I log in to a page with admin credentials, and then I take some actions. and I want to store the value of a textbox.
Then I log out and log in with normal user credential, and I want to check if the value of the text is the same as the value from the first page.
The two scenarios are in the same file.
Can I pass the value of a variable from one scenario to another?
I have tried this:
Scenario: 198422 - SA  
   * def showHandoverChangedValue = script(showHandoverSelect,"function(e){return $(e).val()}")
    * karate.set('showHandoverChangedValue', showHandoverChangedValue)

Scenario: 198422 - TA
    * def showHandoverChangedValue = karate.get("showHandoverChangedValue")
Then match showHandoverNextElementValue == showHandoverChangedValue


So all's good then...

It does not work. if all was good i would not asked :)

Your title is a statement saying you can...

No, this is explained in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080568/143475
Re-use for UI tests is covered in the documentation, that should give you other approaches.

You can use call to get the value from a different call by assigning the call to a varaiable and using json path to get the value you want
* def accountinfo = call read('classpath:adapters/prereqAccountInfo.feature') 

# usage would be something like this
* def varFromCall = accountInfo.response.accountNumber 

You can also pass the variable from the first call to the second using parameters:
* def headers = {accept:"application/json",Content-Type: "application/json"

# pass the variable as such:
call read('classpath:adapters/prereqAccountInfo.feature') { headers: '#(headers)' }

