global variable returns NULL value after upgrading the karate version from 1.4.0.RC3 to 1.5.0.RC4
We have a feature file in which we declared a global variable to use across different scenarios within the same feature file. It was working well until I upgraded my Karate version from 1.4.0.RC3 to 1.5.0.RC4. Now, all the keys are returning NULL values in the tests below. Please provide a solution.
Please find the below example:
Feature: Global Variable Setup Feature
Scenario: Setup Global Variable
* def globalVariable = {}
*karate.set(‘global variable’, globalVariable)
Feature: Global Variable Test feature
@Test1
Scenario: Setting Value to Global Variable

print globalVariable
set globalVariable.key1 = 'test1'
set globalVariable.key2 = 'test2'
print globalVariable
print 'Value of key1 : ',globalVariable. key1

@Test2
Scenario: Fetching value from Testl

print globalVariable
set globalVariable.key3 = 'test3'
print globalVariable

@Test3
Scenario: Fetching value from Test2

print 'Value of key1 : ', globalVariable.key1
print 'Value of key2:', globalVariable.key2
print 'Value of key3 : ', globalVariable.key3

@Test4
Scenario: Fetching value from Test3

print globalVariable
set globalVariable.key3 = 'testA'
print globalVariable

@Test5
Scenario: Fetching value from Test4

print 'Value of key1 : ', globalVariable.key1
print 'Value of key2 : ', globalVariable.key2
print 'Value of key3 : ' globalVariable.key3


I'm sorry, global variables across Scenarios have never been supported in Karate and for reasons best explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080568/143475
If this was working for you, it may have been a bug in previous versions. For now I think your best approach would be to change your tests or dig into the code and prove that there is a bug in Karate.
